# Viewing GIT Repository via plugin/widget/iframe

Tags: html, git, iframe

I want to view my GIT repository and navigate the files on my website on a read only basis. User will be publishing code to this GIT repo and I just want to provide a facility on the site to allow them to navigate the files on a read only basis. I was hoping there was a way to do this using either an iFrame, plugin or some form of widget?

Thanks

Comment: What about [GitWeb](http://progit.org/book/ch4-6.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember using bananajour which lets you publish your git repos locally over your LAN.

https://github.com/toolmantim/bananajour